# algorithm for grouping data based on values

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, correlation, data-analysis

I have a series of plots looking like this:

[image]

The raw data looks like:

```
dataPoint_1, dataPoint_2,dataPoint_3,...
23, 22, 56, ...
14, 13, 68, ...
```

In above diagram, some data points have values close to each other (red, pink, black...) and some are far away from others (green, blue...) And data is keep coming, so the lines are growing longer. Is there an algorithm that can help me find which data points (lines in the diagram) are close and which are not? Not sure whether some statistics algorithms fit into this problem ?

Comment: For starters, you can compute the correlation between each pair of lines.  This will give you a correlation matrix.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Some algorithm, given the data sets, return the groups/clusters. Can you be more specific, how do you define the 'correlation'?

Comment: Tag your question with the language you are using.  Google Pearson or Spearman correlation coefficient.

Comment: Although I'm using c++, but I'm basically looking for a general solution. So is it necessary to tag c++?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried both correlation algorithm you mentioned, it's not the right thing. Basically it's measuring the degree of linear dependence between variables, not the real distance between variables. Say we have three variables: var_1 [1,2,3], var_2 [2,3,4], var_3 [15,16,17], both two correlation algorithm told me the correlation coefficient of three variables are all 1.0. However, if you plot these raw data, you will find var_1 and var_2 are closer, var_3 is not.

Comment: Which correlation coefficient are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tried both Pearson and Spearman

Comment: Correlation will of course consider these series similar. The mean is *subtracted*, and they do have the overall same trend in this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Euclidean. Clearly, the difference between these series is substantial.

You can also try DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) but I'm not sure it adds much here.